# Resizable char buffer container type for C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I'm using libcurl (HTTP transfer library) with C++ and trying to download files from remote HTTP servers. As file is downloaded, my callback function is called multiple times (e.g. every 10 kb) to send me buffer data.

Basically I need something like "string bufer", a data structure to append `char` buffer to existing string. In C, I allocate (`malloc`) a `char*` and then as new buffers come, I `realloc` and then `memcpy` so that I can easily copy my buffer to resized array.

In C, there are multiple solutions to achieve this.

1. I can keep using `malloc`, `realloc`, `memcpy` but I'm pretty sure that they are not recommended in C++.
2. I can use `vector<char>`.
3. I can use `stringstream`.

My use cases is, I'll append a few thousands of items (`char`s) at a time, and after it all finishes (download is completed), I will read all of it at once. But I may need options like `seek` in the future (easy to achieve in array solution (1)) but it is low priority now.

What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for `stringstream`. Just insert into it as you recieve the data, and when you're done you can extract a full `std::string` from it. I don't see why you'd want to `seek` into an array? Anyway, if you know the block size, you can calculate where in the string the corresponding block went.

Comment: I'm implementing a FUSE (file system) wrapper and if file system is gonna have `fseek` call, I need to implement it somehow. Can I dynamically allocate `stringstream` also instead of being in stack?

Comment: You can dynamically allocate anything. But internally a stringstream will be dynamically allocated anyway, so I don't think you need to do it. You can seek on a stringstream in the same way that you seek on any stream.

Comment: Does it have more append time or memory overhead than `vector<char>` solution? What's its plus? Seek is just low priority.

Comment: If you just need to `seek` to a specific char, `stringstream` provides `seekg`. Or just extract the string and use `[]` indexing. If you mean if it is possible to do `new stringstream`, then yes, of course it is. The specifics of how the internal buffer is allocated is probably not guaranteed, and it seems you can't provide your own allocator. __EDIT:__ Wow, I type slow...

Comment: do note that you are not able to support certain symbol (particularly 0x00)

Comment: @YeenFei, what do you mean? I'll use this for binary files too, not just for printing stuff to `stdout`. Is there such a restriction? Doesn't `stringstream` also store NULL (`0x00`) in the middle of string and its `.c_str()` returns a NULL-terminated string?

Comment: @ahmet: Yes `stringstream` has more overhead, because it has to deal with arbitrary I/O operations while you just want to write blocks of data (and do seeks). That's why I said I would use `vector<char>`. But I don't think there will be a big difference, and `stringstream` would probably be slightly more convenient.

Comment: @ahmet, there's no restrition on using 0x00 in a stringstream.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `vector<char>`. But they will all work even with a seek, so your question is really one of style and there are no definitive answers there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if many will agree with this, but for that use case I would actually use a linked list, with each node containing an arbitrarily large array of char that were allocated using `new`.  My reasoning being:

- Items are added in large chunks at a time, one at a time at the back.
- I assume this could use quite a large amount of space, so you avoid reallocation events when a vector would otherwise need more space.
- Since items are read sequentially, the penalty of link lists being unidirectional doesn't affect you.

Should Seeking through the list become a priority, this wouldn't work though.  If it's not a lot of data ultimately, I honestly think a vector would be fine, dispite not being *the* most efficient structure.

Comment: +1 really good idea but full reading and seeking might need considerable amount of implementation and testing, `stringstream` solution makes more reallocation but it is robust and usually safe. I think I'll go for `stringstream` in this trade-off. thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to append char buffers, you can also simply use `std::string` and the member function `append`. On top of that `stringstream` gives you formatting, functionality, so you can add numbers, padding etc., but from your description you appear not to need that.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd use a `deque<char>`. Same interface as `vector`, and vector would do, but vector needs to copy the whole data each time an append exceeds its existing capacity. Growth is exponential, but you'd still expect about `log N` reallocations, where `N` is the number of equal-sized blocks of data you append. Deque doesn't reallocate, so it's the container of choice in cases where a vector would need to reallocate several times.

Assuming the callback is handed a `char*` buffer and length, the code to copy and append the data is simple enough:

```
mydeque.insert(mydeque.end(), buf, buf + len);
```

To get a string at the end, if you want one:

```
std::string mystring(mydeque.begin(), mydeque.end());
```

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by `seek`, but obviously `deque` can be accessed by index or iterator, same as `vector`.

Another possibility, though, is that if you expect a content-length at the start of the download, you could use a `vector` and `reserve()` enough space for the data before you start, which avoids reallocation. That depends on what HTTP requests you're making, and to what servers, since some HTTP responses will use chunked encoding and won't provide the size up front.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `Buffer` class to abstract away the details of the storage. If I were you I would likely implement the buffer based on `std::vector<char>`.